# HttpWebRequest not passing Credentials

Tags: c#, asp.net, httpwebrequest

I'm trying to use `HTTPWebRequest` to access a REST service, and am having problems passing credentials in, see code below. I've read that `NetworkCredential` doesn't support SSL, and I'm hitting an HTTPS site.  Does anyone know of a class similar to `NetworkCredential` that does support SSL?

```
Uri requestUri = null;
Uri.TryCreate("https://mywebserver/webpage", UriKind.Absolute, out requestUri);
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(requestUri);
NetworkCredential nc = new NetworkCredential("user", "password");
request.Credentials = nc;
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get;
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If your server uses NTLM authentication you may try this:

```
CredentialCache cc = new CredentialCache();
cc.Add(
    new Uri("https://mywebserver/webpage"), 
    "NTLM", 
    new NetworkCredential("user", "password"));
request.Credentials = cc;
```

Answer (score 49):

See if it shows up when you use the old-fashioned method:

```
string credentials = Convert.ToBase64String(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes("user"+ ":" + "password"));
request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + credentials);
```

Comment: Could you possibly explain why this would work and not NetworkCredentials?

Answer (score 28):

What kind of authentication mechanism is protecting the web service? The credentials set on `HttpWebRequest` will only be passed through HTTP's `Authorization` header via [Basic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication), [Digest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digest_access_authentication) or [NTLM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTLM). So, if your web service is protected with `WS-Security`, the `NetworkCredentials` will probably not be passed on to the authentication scheme at all, because `WS-Security` doesn't operate at the HTTP level.

What you should do is create a Web Service client proxy for the web service through the command line tool `wsdl.exe` or something similar. That will give you access to Web Service aware authentication schemes.

**Update after comments:**

It seems like `HttpWebRequest` needs to receive the `WWW-Authenticate` challenge with a `401 Unauthorized` before it can authenticate properly over SSL. I guess there's two separate code paths in `HttpWebRequests` handling regular HTTP traffic and encrypted HTTPS traffic. Anyway, what you should try, is:

1. Execute an unauthenticated `HttpWebRequest` to the `https://.../` URI.
2. Receive the `401 Unauthorized` response.
3. Execute the same request, now with both `Credentials` set (not sure if `PreAuthenticate` should be `true` or `false`; test both).
4. You should now get `200 OK` or whatever it is your Web Service responds with.

Another option is to build the `Authorization` header yourself on the initial request:

```
string credentials = String.Format("{0}:{1}", username, password);
byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(credentials);
string base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
string authorization = String.Concat("Basic ", base64);
request.Headers.Add("Authorization", authorization);
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize until now that it is a REST Service I'm calling, so there is now wsdl file.  Also, I'm able to walk the code in the debugger, and I can see it build up the NetworkCredentials object properly, but it just doesn't seem to be getting passed in with the HttpWebRequest.  One more thing - I can successully call the REST service by typing it in to my browser address bar, so it must be using my credentials that way.

Comment: You haven't written what authentication scheme you're using and where you have your credentials from. Plus, if this is a REST service, it shouldn't have a WSDL file. A Web Service with a WSDL file is usually a SOAP Web Service which is the direct opposite of a REST Web Service.

Being able to access the Web Service with a browser (without typing in any credentials?) sounds like it's protected with HTTP authentication, possibly NTLM. Is this true?

Comment: Also, what is the response you get? Is it a `401 Unauthorized`, `403 Forbidden` or something else?

Comment: It's an https site, so the authentication mechanism is SSL - the MSDN online documentation for the NetworkCredential class says it doesn't suport SSL, so I'm thinking that is the problem.  The error I'm getting back is 401 Unauthorized.

Comment: SSL is not an authentication mechanism, it's a cryptographic protocol that provide end-to-end security between the browser and the server. Authentication is orthogonal to SSL and can be done in a number of ways regardless of whether you use SSL or not.

Do you need to enter a username and password when visiting this web service in a browser?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I'm clearly not an expert at this.  I've found out that we are using Basic authentication.  The message I get back when I try to use the NetworkCredential class directly is 401 Unauthorized.  If I try to create a CredentialCache object and add the NetworkCredential object to that, then assign it to the HttpWebRequest.Credentials, then I get a 403 Forbidden error message.  If I hit the service directly in the browser I'm not prompted for credentials, it just works, so I assume the browser is passing my credentials in for me.

Comment: Are your credentials cached in the browser? Which browser are you using? I'm only familiar with one authentication scheme that doesn't actually challenge the user for the credentials like you explain, and that's NTLM, because it can use pre authentication invisibly by sending your Windows credentials to the server. I believe Internet Explorer does this automatically, for instance.

Comment: Just a small comment on this one: I struggled quite a bit getting this example to work, as it has a lowercase "b" in "basic". My server would not authenticate me unless the header contained "Basic" instead of "basic", even though both username and password was correct. Wikipedia also lists this header with a capital "B", so I would advice you to edit your response :)

Comment: I guess this pass the pain text password. Is it possible to encrypt the header?

Comment: @CharithJ, then you should use another authentication scheme than `Basic`, such as `Digest` (RFC 7616) or `Mutual` (RFC 8120).

Answer (score 3):

Try setting request.PreAuthenticate to true.

Comment: According to [this](http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2010/Feb/18/NET-WebRequestPreAuthenticate-not-quite-what-it-sounds-like) it won't work. Still require some work