# Random 401 Unauthorized errors using HttpClient

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, iis-8, dotnet-httpclient

I am using HttpClient to invoke a Web Api REST endpoint and once in a while I see a random 401 Unauthorized Status.

Here is my HttpClient wrapper that was created for re usability purposes. I have modified it to keep it simple for this post without modifying the core parts.

```
public class HttpHelper
{
        public const string JsonContentType = "application/json";

        public T PostAsJsonObject<T>(string uri, T t) where T : class
        {
            using (HttpResponseMessage response = PostJsonHttpRequest(uri, JsonContentType, t))
            {
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                return response.Content.ReadAsAsync<T>().Result;
            }
        }

        private HttpResponseMessage PostJsonHttpRequest<T>(string uri, string contentType, T content) where T : class
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(uri))
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("uri");
            }
            HttpResponseMessage response = CreateHttpClient(contentType).PostAsJsonAsync(uri, content).Result;
            return response;
        }

        private HttpClient CreateHttpClient(string contentType)
        {
           var credentials = new NetworkCredential("srvuser", "somepwd", "somedomain");
           return new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler { Credentials = credentials, PreAuthenticate = true });
        }
}
```

Here is how I am invoking it.

```
var httpHelper = new HttpHelper();
var response = httpHelper.PostAsJsonObject("https://xyz.pvt/inventory/api/orders", "234");
```

Most of the time it works fine, but once in a while I get 401 Unauthorized error. I am trying to figure out what might be causing it.

> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Response status code does not
>   indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized).    at
>   System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()    at
>   HttpHelper.PostAsJsonObject[T](String uri, T t)

I looked at asp.net logs, and found a strange pattern. Most of the time, I see pair of entries (401 followed by 200 OK) such as

```
2017-02-09 12:04:13 104.68.45.152 POST /inventory/api/orders/ - 80 - 132.64.78.120 HTTP/1.1 - 401 2 5 764 
2017-02-09 12:04:16 104.68.45.152 POST /inventory/api/orders/ - 80 somedomain\srvusr 132.64.78.120 HTTP/1.1 - 200 0 0 2917

2017-02-09 12:04:16 104.68.45.152 POST /inventory/api/orders/ - 80 - 132.64.78.120 HTTP/1.1 - 401 2 5 0 
2017-02-09 12:04:19 104.68.45.152 POST /inventory/api/orders/ - 80 somedomain\srvusr 132.64.78.120 HTTP/1.1 - 200 0 0 2230
```

But occasionally I just see 401

```
2017-02-09 12:14:04 104.68.45.152 POST /inventory/api/orders/ - 80 - 132.64.78.120 HTTP/1.1 - 401 2 5 0
```

REST api is implemented using ASP.NET Web Api 2 running on .NET 4.6.1 and in IIS 7.5, it is setup with just Windows Authentication.

Not sure what is causing the authentication to fail once in a while.

**UPDATE:**

Here is the new code that I wrote using async await pattern.

```
public class HttpHelper
{
        public const string JsonContentType = "application/json";

        private HttpClient CreateHttpClient(string url, string contentType)
        {
            var handler = new HttpClientHandler
            {
                Credentials = new CredentialCache { { new Uri(url), "NTLM", new NetworkCredential("srvuser", "somepwd", "somedomain") } },
                PreAuthenticate = true
            };
            var httpClient = new HttpClient(handler);
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue(contentType));
            return httpClient;
        }

        private async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostJsonHttpRequestAsync<T>(string url, string contentType, T content) where T : class
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(url))
            {
                var exception = new ArgumentNullException("url");
                throw exception;
            }

            var response = await CreateHttpClient(url, contentType).PostAsJsonAsync(url, content);

            return response;
        }

        public async Task<T> PostAsJsonObjectAsync<T>(string uri, T t) where T : class
        {
            using (var response = await PostJsonHttpRequestAsync(uri, JsonContentType, t))
            {
                return await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<T>(new[]
                    {
                      new JsonMediaTypeFormatter
                      {
                         SerializerSettings = { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore, TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto }
                      }
                    }.AsEnumerable());
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is how I am finally invoking it.

```
static class TestMe
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var httpHelper = new HttpHelper();
        var responseTask = httpHelper.PostAsJsonObjectAsync("https://xyz.pvt/inventory/api/orders", "234");

        responseTask.Wait(120000);
        var response = responseTask.Result;
        Console.WriteLine(response);
    }
}
```

Even now I see same problem. Still getting random 401 Unauthorized errors.

**UPDATE 2**

I did some more investigation and found that these mysterious 401 errors are coming from IIS. When ever these mysterious 401 error occurs, IIS log has a corresponding 401 error entry, but in this case the request never reaches asp.net pipeline. As if for some reason the request is bounced back by IIS with 401 error.

Without going into too much in depth, I know that windows authentication in IIS uses 2 requests to manage authentication based on how the HttpClient is configured. So a successful authentication request will have a 401.2 followed by 200 OK. It is what happening most of the time. Occasionally thou I notice there is a 401.2, followed by just 401. The same request upon retry attempt goes thru fine (401.2 followed by 200 OK).

Really appreciate if anyone have some insight into this issue and a potential resolution to it.

Comment: I am making some minor corrections to the source code, please bear with me

Comment: Could be your misuse of async in an asp.net context. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13140523/await-vs-task-wait-deadlock

Comment: @Crowcoder, sorry for the confusion. Previously I posted a different sample of code which I was in the middle of refactoring. Please take a look at it now.

Comment: You are still calling `.Result`. I don't know if that is your issue but that should never be done in asp.net. Maybe you can use HttpClientHandler to pre-authenticate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20260013/httpclient-in-net-issues-2-requests-when-providing-username-and-password-in-net

Comment: If you look at my code, I am already doing PreAuthenticate = true. As you saw with my example of previous code prior to my update, I already started the process of getting rid of .Result pattern (it was legacy code implemented around 2 or 3 years ago) and replacing it with async await pattern. Let me see if that resolves the issue.

Comment: Apologies, I went blind after seeing `.Result`.

Comment: I'm having the exact the same behaviour. I also noticed that my requests are getting bounced back by IIS with 401 error. Did you found a solution or some sort of workaround?

Comment: @Skuami I have noticed a pattern, when IIS application pool is being recycled, exactly at that moment if a Http request arrives, I am seeing this behavior. Not all requests run into 401, but seems like a pattern that appears to coincide with IIS app pool recycle. We have a nightly scheduled IIS App pool recycle for the app and these mysterious 401 errors coincide with that recycle event. Not sure if anyone else also experiencing similar behavior. My expectation was that consumers would see maybe 503 or something like that, but not 401, maybe it is a behavior of IIS.

Comment: @Vinod I am facing similar issue. Were you able to find the fix for it?

Answer (score -2):

Are you certain that your code is even the problem?  I don't know the details of your situation, but it's possible the web server is sometimes sending you back 401 responses for no good reason.

Here's something you could do to test this theory: run two (or more) instances of your program simultaneously, ideally on different machines.  Wait until you get the 401 errors.  If all instances of your code start receiving the 401 errors at the same time, then it's almost certainly a problem on the web server.

Comment: Sure, I will try that. BTW... I have retry mechanism in place to get around this issue. But I feel like that is a band aid fix. Trying to understand the root cause of these mysterious 401 errors.