# Authorization Required, Remote server returned an error in C# when using HttpWebResponse

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

I have gone through various post regarding this but still didn't get proper answer. Maybe i might not have gone through the proper link. 
Here is my question. Am using HttpWebRequest and when i try to request the open link, the code works perfectly but when i try to request the secured link, it shows remote server returned an error and and authentication required. 401.

When i try to request this [link](http://echo.jsontest.com/key/value/one/two). It works perfectly. But when i try to access secured link, it shows those errors. You can check that in following code.

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.securedlink.com/fileupload.php");
            HttpHeader a = Config.GetCred;
            request.Headers[a.Key] = a.Value;
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "pswd");

            request.BeginGetRequestStream
            ((result =>
                {
                    using (Stream requestStream = request.EndGetRequestStream(result))
                    {
                        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(requestStream))
                        {
                            writer.Write(str);
                            writer.Flush();
                        }
                    }

                    request.BeginGetResponse((responseResult =>
                        {
                            try
                            {

                                var webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(responseResult); 
                                using (var responseStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream())
                                {
                                    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
                                    {
                                        string srresult = streamReader.ReadToEnd(); 
                                        Debug.WriteLine(srresult);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            catch (WebException ex)      // Remote server returned an error
                            {
                                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(ex.Response.GetResponseStream()))
                                {
                                    string ssresult = reader.ReadToEnd();
                                    Debug.WriteLine(ssresult);  // ssresult shows Authorization Required.

                                }
                            }
                        }), null);

                }), null);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry everyone. As mentioned, i forget to go through this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7091203/c-sharp-network-credentials-not-being-passed-to-server). I passed the headers as mentioned in that question and everything works fine. Thank you. :)