# How do I login with WebRequest when protected with a .htacces password file?

Tags: c#, .htaccess, httpwebrequest, webrequest

I want to login using the `WebRequest` class.

```
var http = WebRequest.Create("http://www.xxx.nl/admin/xxx.php?id=3005");
```

I think I need to do something with the `NetworkCredential` Class but do I only need to fill in the username and password?

Also, I don't know how I would eventually receive the page data.

Comment: this StackOverFlow previous posting might help you out.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1702426/httpwebrequest-not-passing-credentials

Comment: Thank you DJ KRAZE did not know it was that easy! :D

Answer (score 2):

You need to provide an implementation of the `ICredentials` class to `WebRequest`. `NetworkCredentials` is an implementation of `ICredentials` that you can use.

The specific details will depend on your .htaccess file. I'll assume that your'e using basic authentication with usernames and passwords defined in the .htaccess file. You'll need to create a new `NetworkCredentials` object and pass in the username and password defined in the .htaccess file. I'm not 100% sure, but you might need to set the `NetworkCredentials.Domain` property to match the "realm" defined in the .htaccess file.

Have a look at [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/71b57yke.aspx) for an example of how to create a `NetworkCredentials` instance and use it with a `WebRequest` instance.