# Accessing bitbucket api 403 Forbidden

Tags: c#, bitbucket-api

I am trying to develop a `c#` application which sends some `HttpWebRequest` to **BitBucket** API.
I am trying to access the below URL.

```
https://bitbucket.org/api/1.0/repositories/MyUserName/MyRepo/changesets
```

C# Code

```
string url = "https://bitbucket.org/api/1.0/repositories/MyUserName/MyRepo/changesets";
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("MyUserName", "MyPassword");
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

This gives me `403 error` which means credentials are correct but those credentials do not grant the caller permission to access the resource.

I don't know how to fix do this. I guess some configurations must do in bitbucket  but have no idea. I am the owner of this repository.

Please advice me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding header like below solve my issue.

```
request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(new ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes("username:password")));
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't mean that credentials are correct.

You cannot use NetworkCredential that way. Please read the only line describing [NetworkCredentials](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkcredential.aspx)

You have to:

- Simulate login process.
- Get the cookies
- Create
  [CookiesAwareWebClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4740752/how-to-login-with-webclient-c-sharp)

Comment: according to the API it says that https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Use+the+Bitbucket+REST+APIs#UsetheBitbucketRESTAPIs-Authentication

Comment: Did you read the link?
Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1702426/httpwebrequest-not-passing-credentials