# Should we need to regenerate SAS token after deleting and re-creating the azure logic app workflow

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I have a logic app, which is calling another logic app. I have deleted all logic apps and recreated them. So, now when accessing 2nd logic app from 1st logic app getting 403 error with error message

**The web app you have attempted to reach has blocked your access**.

Could you please provide information on this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the error output:

> The web app you have attempted to reach has blocked your access.

I think the issue is not comes from the logic app side.

Your logic app looks like trying to access web app(app service), but your app service has some limitation. Try to [remove these limitations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68184464/6261890). Or try to meet the requirement of the web app. If your web app require auth identity to access, please create system identity of your logic app and assign it required permission to access the target web app(Since all of the logic apps has been re-created, all of the previous identities should already disappeared.).