# How to fix 403 blank page error on Azure Web Service site & SSH connection?

Tags: javascript, azure, express, azure-web-app-service

I've recently created a web app on Azure using Express and Node 18. It's worked for development locally, but when I tried to host it on an Azure web app, I couldn't get it to show. The site did not show anything, and sent back a 403 error in the console. The same happened when I tried to SSH into the server to get more info:

```
Pinging app default url...
Ping responded with status code: 403
Checking status, body: {"port":2222,"state":"STOPPED","canReachPort":false,"msg":"Unable to connect to WebApp"}
```

I've tried looking up other solutions, but they all seem to refer to a Dockerfile, which I think is created in the process of sending the app to Azure. I'm not sure how to edit this file, but I seem to be experiencing similar errors (`Container didn't respond to HTTP pings on port 8080, failing site start`)

I've tried setting the Express port to 3000, 443, and 8080, and changing the WEBSITE_PORT and PORT env variables, none of which have changed anything.

```
import express from "express";
import session from "express-session";

const app = express(); // Create express app

app.listen(process.env.PORT); // Listen on port 8080
```

I'm quite new to Express and Azure, and the slightly confusing nature of the Azure portal has not helped, so any assistance is greatly appreciated!

Comment: When you created the Web App, did you select Code or Docker Container as the Publish method?

Comment: I selected code

Answer (score 0):

While I deploy the express app into web app got the same 403 error.

[image]

- 403 error can appear if these restrictions prevent your requests from being processed.
- It will occur when attempting to access the resources from a particular IP address or from restricted networks.

[image]

I created web app in azure with node 18 version runtime that as you mentioned.

[image]

I created Express node application in my local.

[image]

The express app run successfully in Local.

[image]

I deployed express app to web app and ran it successfully.

[image]

[image]

- Create network security groups, firewall rules, or IP limitations for your resources using Azure.  And enable access services.

For more information, refer this [SO LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67283993/azure-app-service-returns-error-error-403-forbidden-the-web-app-you-have-att)